# Can having a short break help improve at Go?

Tags: go

I'd like to know if taking a little break can be a good idea in go.
I've read several threads saying that people became stronger after a short break.

Can it be true ? Is there some subconscious learning while not practising ?
Is there a possibility to forget bad habits during this period ? And how long should the break be ?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it's not question about games but about psychology.

Comment: @tsuma534 : isn't it specific to Go ? I haven't heard about another-board game player that has became stronger without playing. I may be wrong though.

Comment: I have became better at many games after a break. It isn't a game specific phenomenon, as it also occured for my other hobbies. Also, the correlation between the break and the improvement doesn't necessarily imply a causation - there are too many factors that should be taken into account.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, it **CAN**. There is no warranty that a short break will improve your Go, but it can help. Take a typical vacation (about two weeks) as a good measure for the time.

The probably best recipe for improving Go is quite to the contrary: Do every day **something** with Go, 10 minutes per day are sufficient (e.g., solving a life and death problem or finding a tesuji).

Personally, I found the playing over-the-board tournaments (being immersed with Go one weekend long) helps a lot.